# How to use Moq to unit test method which has Func as parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

My static method is following. The problem is that my code is not injecting object/class implementing interface, but it uses Func as method parameter. How to mock it with Moq?

```
public class Repeater
    {
        const int NumberOfReapetsWithException = 5;

        public static async Task<string> RunCommandWithException(Func<string, Task<string>> function, string parameter,
             ILoggerService logger = null, string messageWhileException = "Exception while calling method for the {2} time", bool doRepeatCalls = false)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            var result = "";

            for (; true; )
            {
                try
                {
                    result = await function(parameter);
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (doRepeatCalls)
                    {
                        string message = HandleException<string, string>(parameter, null, logger, messageWhileException, ref counter, e);

                        if (counter > NumberOfReapetsWithException)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
...
}   }
```

Comment: Do you have to use Moq for some reason? You could simply create your own Func object within the unit test.

Comment: Any example? Generally I'd like to be able to count how much time it was started. I know I can create new class with property which can be incremented with each start:). But i'd like to use Moq;)

Comment: just create a function and use that there is no need for Moq. within the function you can count the number of times it is called. Side note. your design should be refactored. Repeater could be refactored to not have to use static method

Answer (score 1):

When having a Func object as a parameter you could simply send in the wanted mock behavior (When using Moq you create an object and then set its behavior with a mock delegate).

```
    [TestCase] // using nunit
    public void sometest()
    {
        int i = 0;
        Func<string, Task<string>> mockFunc = async s =>
        {
            i++; // count stuff
            await Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine("Awating stuff"); });
            return "Just return whatever";
        };
        var a = Repeater.RunCommandWithException(mockFunc, "mockString");

    }
```